# Advance Find Functionality in CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

In Advance Find View, how to find who last accessed or run the advanced find view which is already created by someone?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking: Are you trying to use "Advanced Find" to query information - or are you asking about tracing "Advanced Find" usage?

Comment: I want to tracing "Advance Find" Usage and find out last accessed by user.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Plugin with a Step registered on the `Retrieve` Message (Post-Operation, asynchronous) and log the retrieved userquery and executing user to a custom entity.

In CRM 2016 however MS introduced a lot of optimizations which target to reuse retrieved userquery and userform data as much as possible so your plugin will not fire for repeated use.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error @Filburt, I ended up deleting my answer since yours covers what I would have to change mine to.

Comment: But this doesn't mean that each time plugin fired from `Advanced Find`, 
it could from some code behind or other views.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Dynamics CRM Does not have this kind of provision itself. You need to write custom code which is a plugin. Create a new entity so that you can create record in it using plugin. Now Create a synchronous Plugin on `RetrieveMultiple` message, create record in it with **logged in user** attribute. This way you can get the log.